# JUnit 4 test case passes when debugged but fails when ran

Tags: eclipse, debugging, junit4, java-6

I'm using Eclipse Helios Service Release 2, Java 6 and JUnit 4.

I've got a test case that passes when I debug it by itself and fails when I run it by itself. The failure is coming from the line

`FileUtils.deleteDirectory(target);`

with the error

`ERROR [main] (MyRequestHandler.java:56) - An unexpected error occurred when processing MyRequestHandler
java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file: \apps\Codes\MP2\LandingStrips\inprocess\12345\testTarDir\myfile.txt`

In both cases the call `File.canWrite();` is coming back true before the proram attempts to delete it. The only other things I know is that the runtime arguments during debug are

`[-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:2914, -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252]`

and during run are

`[-Dfile.encoding=Cp1252]`

I'm not sure what that means or if it matters, but for the sake of providing as much background as possible there it is.

EDIT- Full stack trace:

`ERROR [main] (MyRequestHandler.java:56) - An unexpected error occurred when processing MyRequestHandler
java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file: \apps\Codes\MP2\LandingStrips\inprocess\12345\testTarDir\myfile.txt
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:1643)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:1268)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:1200)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.forceDelete(FileUtils.java:1634)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.cleanDirectory(FileUtils.java:1268)
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:1200)
    at com.codes.requesthandler.MyRequestHandler.deleteDirectory(MyRequestHandler.java:74)
    at com.codes.requesthandler.MyRequestHandler.process(MyRequestHandler.java:50)
    at com.codes.requesthandler.MyRequestHandlerTest.processWithProperArguments(MyRequestHandlerTest.java:135)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)`

Comment: what else is in the stack trace?

Comment: perhaps the debugger/eclipse is holding lock on the file? or the file is open in another program?

Comment: The file shouldn't be open in any other program because it's created in the setUp() for the test, and as far as Ecplise holding a lock on it is there a way to check besides File.canWrite()?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly related .. I had a JUnit test that I would run from the command line that created a new data file and compared its contents with an existing data file using the org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.contentEquals() method from the Apache Commons IO library - which I'm sure wraps the Java IO classes.  The unit test passes if the contents of the new file match the contents of the old file exactly.

I always run the unit test using Ant in a separate terminal window - and not via Eclipse.
Just by having the project open in Eclipse would cause the test to fail approximately 25% of the time.  (I ran the test repeatedly in a loop 1000 times and it would fail on average 250 of those times.)  I suspect that the Eclipse Java Builder or one of the Eclipse plugins I have installed sometimes interfered with JUnit's access to the newly created data file.

Trying it today, I couldn't get the test to fail.  Something in my project's or Eclipse's setup may have changed. I don't know what.

So my suggestion is to attempt to run your unit test via Ant - outside of Eclipse and with the project not open in Eclipse.